# Prevent duplicate pages from being added

Tags: posts, multisite, pages, query, duplicates

Im using this code to prevent duplicate post from being added but i also need to prevent duplicate pages too. Can Someone please help?

```
function clearDuplicatePosts(){
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $wpdb->query("DELETE bad_rows . * FROM ".$prefix."posts AS bad_rows INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ".$prefix."posts.post_title, MIN( ".$prefix."posts.ID ) AS min_id
    FROM ".$prefix."posts
    GROUP BY post_title
    HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
    ) AS good_rows ON ( good_rows.post_title = bad_rows.post_title
    AND good_rows.min_id <> bad_rows.ID )");
} 
add_action('publish_post', 'clearDuplicatePosts');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the same function simply hook it to the `publish_page` hook
or any custom post type for that matter `publish_{post type name}`

so just add :

```
add_action('publish_page', 'clearDuplicatePosts');
```